# Schedule automatic update of Excel 2010 file with MS Query data?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, scheduled-tasks, ms-query

I thought this would be easy, but apparently not.

I have a stored procedure that returns a dynamic result set. Loading it into excel using

```
Data -> From Other Sources -> MS Query -> exec MyProc
```

gets the data I need into the spreadsheet, formatted the way I want (e.g. Blue headers with filters in place, zebra stripes, etc).

I would like to set this up on a share somewhere, and have a scheduled job run nightly to update the data. I figured there would be a command line switch that would do it, but I don't see that happening. I can use Scheduled Tasks or Tidal Enterprise Scheduler as needed to get this done.

I don't want it to be refreshed when users open it, as it takes 1-2 minutes to refresh. Is what I'm doing possible without hack-arounds?

Comment: How about creating an INSERT query that uses your proc and loads the results into a table, schedule that and then point MS Query at the table instead of the proc and switch it to refresh on open. Would that solve your refresh time issue?